# Странный illegal string offset или base64

Tags: php, массивы, base64, drupal7

Есть загрузка в массив картинки в формате base64.

```
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,'. base64_encode($data);
$data['numOne'] = strval($base64);
```

А есть загрузка в массив картинки в формате ссылки.

```
$data['numOne'] = file_create_url($file->uri);
```

Оба возвращают строку.

Но в первом примере выходит ошибка. При этом если вставить готовый результат виде строки в первый пример то всё работает.

> illegal string offset

---

Заметил, что  я использую одну и тужу переменную.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы формируете строку картинки

```
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,'. base64_encode($data);
```

из этой строки можно предположить, что `$data` - это строковый контент вашей картинки, а никак не массив. Но в следующей строке вы обращаетесь к `$data` как к массиву

```
$data['numOne'] = ...;
```

что и вызывает ошибку

> illegal string offset

поскольку строке тоже можно обратиться как к массиву, но индекса 'numOne' в нем нет